# VBA - How to remove string of characters in a range cell

Tags: vba, excel, datetime, format

This is the value of my date `Mar 30 2016  4:46:34:256PM` i want to remove the *Time* to make it like this `Mar 30 2016`.

I've tried various ways to format this if value with the *format* like `mm-dd-yyyy` , `mm-dd-yyyy` , `yyyy-mm-dd etc`. it's working but if tried this `Mar 30 2016  4:46:34:256PM` as value it's not working. can someone please tell me why?

I tried a simple code to test all the formats but it's not working with this value `Mar 30 2016  4:46:34:256PM` so i decided to remove the `4:46:34:256PM` and that's how i got stock....

```
Sub formateDate()
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow

Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = ("dd-mm-yyyy")
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is `Mar 30 2016  4:46:34:256PM` an actual date, or a string? If Excel doesn't recognise a text as a date, it can not change it's formatting. Either make sure you enter actual dates in the cells, then format them, or you need to go wild with text and date functions to extract the date only.

Comment: To verify (as @vacip suggests) check the `Cells(i, 2).Value2`. If it is a number then the dates are stored as dates and you can format them using the `.NumberFormat`. If that's not the case and you get a string back for `.Value2` then you'll have to extract the date from the string first (nightmare).

Comment: @vacip its an actual date but im going to define it as range so i can use the *NumberFormat*

Comment: @Ralph thats exactly what i'm thinkimg! But is it possible to just remove the hh:mm:ss etc.?

Comment: If it was an actual date, then just use `.NumberFormat="mmm dd yyyy"` If this doesn't work, then it is not a date. Have you tried what Ralph suggested? The .Value2 thing? What does it return?

Comment: @vacip i just tried Ralph suggestion it return the `Mar 30 2016 4:46:34:256PM` it's not an actual date, but how can i remove the `4:46:34:256PM`?

Comment: the actual problem is this *Mar 30 2016 4:46:34:256PM* there are no datetime format whatever like this i dont even know what _:256_ is maybe millisec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your example you seem to have two consecutive spaces after the year number

should it always be so you could go like follows

```
Cells(i, 2) = Left(Cells(i, 2), InStr(Cells(i, 2), "  ") - 1)
```

and then you can also assign it date formats since `IsDate` WorksheetFunction returns `True` if called on the resulting values

Comment: Thanks for your answer im going to try this once i get home

Comment: What's your need? You can build a string with any format by dissecting and concatenating strings. But if you want Excel to recognize it as a time format you must look for it in the number format menu. Besides that, if my solution anwered your question please mark it as accepted. Thank you